# Jquery - How to affect just one node in drupal view

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, view

When I click a node in a drupal view it toggles the body for every node in my view instead of just the node I am clicking. How can I get jquery to toggle just the node I am clicking? Here is my code in the head of my node template (node-type.tpl.php)

```
 <script>
 $("button").click(function () {
 $(".more").toggle();
 });
 </script>
```

And the code for the body to be toggled.

```
 <div class="more"><?php print $node->content['body']['#value']; ?></div>
```

Currently it toggles every div with the class "more" in my entire view instead of just in the node which I am clicking. How do I restrict it to just the clicked node?

I would also like it if only body were open at a time. ie; when a different node is clicked,  the previous node's body toggles closed.

I'm sure it's probably easy but I just can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: It would help to see the final HTML and not the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the button relative to `.more`?

If the button is in the `.more` element, you want to do something like this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $('.more').hide();
    $(this).closest(".more").show();
});
```

If the button is not a parent or ancestor of `.more`, you will need to do a little more.  If the buttons are in the same order as the `.more` elements (and there aren't any unrelated buttons), you can do this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $('.more').hide();
    $('.more').eq( $('button').index( $(this) ) ).show();
});
```

However, you are better off linking the button to the `.more` content with an `id` and a `href`, or some jQuery data:

```
<button class='morebutton' data-more="#more1">Button 1</button>
<button class='morebutton' data-more="#more2">Button 2</button>
<div class='more' id="more1">More Number 1</div>
<div class='more' id="more2">More Number 2</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".morebutton").click(function () {
    $('.more').hide();
    $( $(this).data('more') ).show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/EfUxt/

There are libraries that help with these kinds of situations, such as jQuery UI Tabs.

Comment: Here's the error I got with the first option;  `$(this).closest is not a function
[Break On This Error] $(this).closest(".more").show();`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: And I don't think the first option is what you want.  Is your button inside of `.more'?  If so, it would be hidden...  I guess I need to know what your html structure (including the buttons) looks like.

Comment: No problem.  Could you accept my answer?  (Click the checkmark under the number next to this answer)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want jQuery UI tabs http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ or some other jQuery tabs solution.